# Bash: all of array except last element

Tags: bash

Bash has a neat way of giving all elements in an array except the first:

```
"${a[@]:1}"
```

To get all except the last I have found:

```
"${a[@]:0:$((${#a[@]}-1))}"
```

But, man, that is ugly.

Is there an elegant alternative?

Comment: You can hack with `b=("${a[@]}"); unset "b[-1]"; do_whatever_with "${b[@]}"`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am not sure how much improvement it would be, but you can drop the arithmetic operator (`$(())`) and starting index (`0` here):

```
${a[@]::${#a[@]}-1}
```

So:

```
$ foo=( 1 2 3 )

$ echo "${foo[@]::${#foo[@]}-1}"
1 2
```

As you can see, the improvement is purely syntactical; the idea remains the same.

Comment: Note for zsh users: the simplification works if you keep the starting index.